# How to convert raw json from a url to json or csv?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I have a URL that is providing me with raw json-based data, and I am having some trouble importing that raw text as a json file, or even converting it to a csv.

I have tried using urllib3 and BeautifulSoup to import that data, and store it as a soup object. What I am not able to do is store that data as json and csv (I need both).

One of the issues I believe is causing this problem is the presence of a line at the top of the page describing the results returned, but is not technically part of the json data:

#### Code at the top that may be causing the issue:

```
{
"response":{"numFound":1161,"start":0,"docs":[
  {
    "applicationType":"UTILITY",
    "documentId":"US10010749B2",
    "applicationNumber":"US14422067",
```

#### Libraries I am using:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
```

#### Some Code:

```
url = "https://developer.uspto.gov/ibd-api/v1/patent/application?assignee=alexander&start=0&rows=5"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

print(soup)

json_data = json.load(url)
print(json_data)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

My ultimate goal is to be able to "organize and download" all the data from the url and store them in json and csv formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is mostly correct:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://developer.uspto.gov/ibd-api/v1/patent/application?assignee=alexander&start=0&rows=5"
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

json_data = json.loads(soup.text)
print(json_data)
```

Having the right json data, you can import it into a panda dataframe and then export it to csv:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data['response']['docs'])
df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False)
```

**EDIT**

Added code for exporting to csv

Comment: Thanks Sebastien. The issue is still that first line being treated as part of the file. I am trying to get rid of:
{
  "response":{"numFound":1161,"start":0,"docs":[

...as well as the "}" at the end.

Comment: you want to save each doc as a line in your csv file ?

Comment: Yes, where each column is one of the attributes above, and each line is a different patent document

Comment: do you need `numFound` attribute?

Comment: Nope, just the results themselves

Comment: Thanks Sebastien! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have mistaken how to load JSON using `json.load`. A simple fix is shown below.

```
if response.code == 200:
     json_data = json.load(response.data)
     print(json_data)
```

This returns the data in a dictionary format. You can then convert it to a CSV file. Here is some sample code for that:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
for key in json_data.keys():
    f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key, json_data[key]))
```

Comment: You can get the individual documents by then iterating over `json_data['response']['docs']`

Comment: @Vaibhav Bajaj Thanks. Can you explain what the "response.code == 200" means?

Comment: @TomNash Thanks. Do you mean to iterate for the purposes of converting that to a CSV?

Comment: @alkhalifas response.code == 200 checks if your HTTP request succeeded. 200 is the code for a Success, like 404 is for Page Not Found.